# libgit2sharp: how to set multiple values with same key

Tags: libgit2sharp

how do I set multiple values for a config-key? Some sections supports multiple values:

```
[remote "origin"]
   url = git@github.com:schacon/simplegit-progit.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
   fetch = +refs/heads/qa/*:refs/remotes/origin/qa/*
```

Something like this is not working in gitLib2Sharp:

```
string[] refSpecs = {"+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master", "+refs/heads/qa/*:refs/remotes/origin/qa/*"};
repo.Config.Set( @"remote.origin.fetch", refSpec );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I set multiple values for a config-key

This is indeed a currently missing feature in LibGit2Sharp. An **[issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/586)** has just been opened to track this.

However, if what you're after is setting/updating the default refspecs of a remote, the `repo.Network.Remotes.Update()` method may already fit that need without having to wait for the issue to be fixed.

- Pull request **[#567](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/553)** recently enhanced the `Remotes.Update()` method to make it cope with refspecs updation. As such, your example could be fulfilled with the following code.

```
    var fetchSpecs = new string[]
    {
        "+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master",
        "+refs/heads/qa/*:refs/remotes/origin/qa/*"
    };

    using (var repo = new Repository(path))
    {
        var remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
        repo.Network.Remotes.Update(remote, r => r.FetchRefSpecs = fetchSpecs);
    }
```

- More or less related, pull request **[#553](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/553)** introduced an easy way to enumerate all the refspecs of a remote